# can't compare datetime.date to bool

Tags: python, python-2.7, date, datetime, odoo-10

when i save the atttachment i get this error  " can't compare datetime.date to bool "
how can i solve thit issue
this is the code

```
 from datetime import datetime, date, timedelta
 from odoo import models, fields, api, _
 from odoo.exceptions import Warning


class HrEmployeeDocument(models.Model):
_name = 'hr.employee.document'
_description = 'HR Employee Documents'



@api.constrains('expiry_date')
def check_expr_date(self):
    for each in self:
        exp_date = each.expiry_date
        if expiry_date < date.today():
            raise Warning('Your Document Is Already Expired.')

expiry_date = fields.Date(string='Expiry Date', copy=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

The expiry_date value is null therefore when retrieved via odoo orm it is retrieved as a `False`, thus you are unable to compare a `Datetime` object to a `Bool`.

Must set a default parameter if the logic will not provide a timestamp during record creation. Or you can check for a false

For example: `expiry_date = fields.Date(string='Expiry Date', default=fields.Date.context_today, copy=False)`

See [Odoo ORM API](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/14.0/developer/reference/addons/orm.html#basic-fields) for more details.

Answer (score -1):

The issue is this line

```
expiry_date = fields.Date(string='Expiry Date', copy=False)
```

In the documentation of the `odoo`->`field`, it requires a date string, what you provided `string='Expiry Date'`, which is meanless, thus the `expiry_date` will be assigned a bool which is `False`, since it is not a valid data string.

You need to change to:

```
expiry_date = fields.Date(string='2014-06-15', copy=False)
```

And it should work.

Hope this helps.

Comment: @MohamedFouad, I couldn't run your code locally, because the odoo takes to long to install. Hope my answer helps.

Comment: i'am changing the code and Added if self.expiry_date: 
it work well if the field is empty but if the date is set i get this error "  can't compare datetime.date to str "

Comment: One of the parameters available to fields is string as defined by odoo docs: "string (str) – the label of the field seen by users; if not set, the ORM takes the field name in the class (capitalized)."  You are mixing it up with the default parameter.